# Filtering the values from 2D array of compounds, elements and oxidation states

Tags: python

I have a list of compounds which have the molecular formula in the pattern: ABO3, where A and B represent two different atoms and O represents Oxygen. I saved the list in the form of `['A','B','O'].`

```
list2 = [ ['Ba', 'Si', 'O'],

 ['Ca', 'Mn', 'O'],

 ['Ca', 'Fe', 'O']]
```

I can call oxidation states of elements (Only 'A' and 'B' not 'O') as A_OS and B_OS.

I want to extract from the list, sets of atoms (A and B) such that at least one of their oxidation state sums up to 6. That is A_OS + B_OS = 6 and discard their other oxidation states (if any). I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
from mendeleev import element
import pandas as pd
for i in range(len(list2)):
  print('\n', list2[i], end=" ",  sep=' ', flush=True)
  for j in range(len(list2[i])-1):
    print(element(list2[i][j]).oxistates,end=" ",sep=' ',flush=True)
```

The Output is:

```
Compound          A_OS                   B_OS

['Ba', 'Si', 'O'] [2] [4, -4, 2]

['Ca', 'Mn', 'O'] [2] [7, 6, 4, 3, 2] 

['Ca', 'Fe', 'O'] [2] [3, 2]
```

One can see Si, Mn and Fe have multiple oxidation states. I want only that Oxidation state which sums up such that A_OS + B_OS = 6 and to remove other oxidation states. That is **if** A_OS + B_OS != 6 remove that compound from the list.

My desired output is like this:

```
['Ba', 'Si', 'O'] [2] [4]

['Ca', 'Mn', 'O'] [2] [4]
```

and remove this compound
`['Ca', 'Fe', 'O'] [2] [3, 2]`  as any combination does not result in (A_OS + B_OS = 6).

Could you please help me in refactoring my code to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's only consider the case of a single compound. We can loop over this approach to apply it to all compounds we care about later.

Now, for the compound specified by your list `['Ba', 'Si', 'O']`, you want to first find the oxidation states of all elements except Oxygen:

```
compound = ['Ba', 'Si', 'O']
oxid_states = [element(elem).oxistates
               for elem in compound
               if elem != 'O']
```

This should give us a list of lists, where the `x`th inner list tells us the oxidation states of the `x`th element in the list `compound`. For our example of `compound = ['Ba', 'Si', 'O']`, we'd get `oxid_states = [[2], [4, -4, 2]]`

Now, we want to find the [*cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all these lists, and only keep those that sum up to six. We can do this using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Note that this needs us to `import itertools`.

```
valid_oxid_states = [oxid_vals
                     for oxid_vals in itertools.product(*oxid_states)
                     if sum(oxid_vals) == 6]
```

For our example, this gives the result `valid_oxid_states = [(2, 4)]`

If there was no combination that summed to 6, this would be an empty list. If there was more than one combination, this list would have multiple elements. In each element, the `x`th integer corresponds to the oxidation state of the `x`th element in `compound`. Since you want two separate lists in your output, we can do that now:

```
elem_oxid_states = [list(o) for o in zip(*valid_oxid_states)]
```

which would give the result `elem_oxid_states = [[2], [4]]`

---

To apply this to multiple compounds, let's first put all of this code in a function:

```
from mendeleev import element
import itertools

def get_valid_oxid_states(compound, total):
    oxid_states = [element(elem).oxistates
                   for elem in compound
                   if elem != 'O']

    valid_oxid_states = [oxid_vals
                         for oxid_vals in itertools.product(*oxid_states)
                         if sum(oxid_vals) == total]

    elem_oxid_states = [list(o) for o in zip(*valid_oxid_states)]
    return elem_oxid_states
```

And call this function for each compound in `list2`:

```
list2 = [ ['Ba', 'Si', 'O'],
 ['Ca', 'Mn', 'O'],
 ['Ca', 'Fe', 'O']]

for compound in list2:
    # If no valid states found, ox_states will be empty
    ox_states = get_valid_oxid_states(compound, 6)
    if ox_states: 
        # print only if ox_states is not empty
        print(compound, *ox_states)
```

Which gives the required output:

```
['Ba', 'Si', 'O'] [2] [4]
['Ca', 'Mn', 'O'] [2] [4]
```